# Paypal Error PayPal gateway has rejected request. %1 in Magento2.2.8

Tags: magento2, paypal, paypal-express, magento2.2.8

I just setup paypal checkout system but after paypal payment window it redirects me to store page to place an order to store the order in backend orders panel.

but when i press the button to place an order system gives me the following error

```
PayPal gateway has rejected request. %1
```

Comment: You need to put proper or correct address for shipping during checkout.

Comment: well all its fine but it still doing ...

Comment: im getting this now No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue

Comment: can you please tell me, how you resolved this error ?

Comment: Can you please tell me the solution of this